# How to check whether query gets a result or not

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I'm trying to grab some data from a database using a simple 'select' query but I'm not getting any data back.  When I run the same query letter by letter in the Toad editor for oracle, I get the data just fine.

In C#

```
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //cmd contains the query
DataTable dtHRSinfo = new DataTable();

while (reader.Read()) // no lines to read
{
    dtHRSinfo.Rows.Add(reader); // never comes to this statement!
}
```

EDIT:
I also have this alternate method that works for my other queries but not for this one. This method also doesn't give any values to the data table.

```
dtHRSinfo.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

The query

```
select unitid,lasttimeon,lasttimeoff,currentlyon,currentcallontime, currentcallofftime

from opr.mktunit
```

I don't get any errors or exceptions.  The db reader never gets the values and they are never assigned to the datatable. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

The DB connection

```
public bool OpenDBConnections(string user, string pass)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Log("Connection to Database");
            cnOprPrd = new OdbcConnection();
            cnOprPrd.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=OPRPRD;Uid=" + user + ";Pwd=" + pass;
            cnOprPrd.Open();
            //INPUT FOLDER
            sqlFolder = AC2_SQL_FOLDER;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

I fixed the problem by typing in my command explicitly into a string variable rather than using a Streamreader to read the string from a file.

The issue may have arisen from some unrecognizable character sequences from the streamreader. Thanks for the answers, guys.

Comment: Normally when you see the tags [C#] and [sql] together you assume MS Sql Server, but in you post you mention Oracle. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Check if reader.HasRows == true

Comment: I would also highly recommend using an ORM framework like Entity Framework and avoid a lot of these types of situations. A Quick Google yielded [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely your connection string. Debug the cmd object or show us the code where you set the connection string. We also need to talk about Disposing unmanaged resource classes... Use the `using` syntax to ensure that your connections are properly cleaned up:

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())  //cmd contains the query
{
    DataTable dtHRSinfo = new DataTable();

    while (reader.Read()) // no lines to read
    {
        dtHRSinfo.Rows.Add(reader); // never comes to this statement!
    }
}
```

**[More about the using statement here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

This block:

```
while (reader.Read()) // no lines to read
{
    dtHRSinfo.Rows.Add(reader); // never comes to this statement!
}
```

looks odd. I've never seen an extension method that adds rows to a data table one row at a time *directly from a data reader*.

I would expect to see the [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb.aspx) method used instead:

```
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //cmd contains the query
DataTable dtHRSinfo = new DataTable();

dtHRSinfo.Load(reader);
```

My guess is that it's using an overload of `Add` that is implicitly adding the value of `reader.ToString()` to the first column.

Comment: I tried both ways to no avail.  I am using the .LOAD(reader) method for some other queries and they are working just fine. But for this one I can't figure out why its the data isn't sticking.

Answer (score 1):

from What I suggest if you can connect to your Database  this should be simple  try this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleConnection connection;
OracleDataAdapter OracleAdapter;
connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        connection.Open();
        OracleAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["your select statement"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        OracleAdapter.Fill(ds, "your table name");
```

using the fill method will populate all data from database table into you dataset.

to use configurationManager.Appsetting   refrence to

```
using System.Configuration;
```

add a configuration file and externalize your select query  use the key value   tags in

```
<appSettings>
<addKey="your select statement" value 
"select unitid,lasttimeon,lasttimeoff,currentlyon,currentcallontime, currentcallofftime
from opr.mktunit"/>
```

see if this works for you let me know. Cheers